# C# How can I give a textbox focus when a key is pressed?

Tags: c#

When the '-' minus key is pressed I want to jump to a certain textbox on my form and have the cursor flashing in that textbox. How can I do this?

Thanks
Steven

Answer (score 3):

You must handle the KeyDown event for your form, and check for the "-" key.  Try this:

```
private void form1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode = Keys.OemMinus)
    {
            textBox1.Focus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can handle the key press event in the form as following.

 void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.KeyChar == 45)
                {
                   //Higlight the text box. Call the Select() method of the textbox
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a event that set focus to certain Text Box,

next You need to create a key listener that fire that event when the '-' is pressed, the You need to add that listener in the palace where this functionality is available.

txtBox.Focus();

Answer (score 0):

You must get the `onKeyDown` event of your form and there you can do something like `textbox.focus();`